# How do I inject a dependency into a Jersey resource?

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey to build a REST API, with Grizzly.  I'm not using any dependency injection framework like Google Guice.

One of the resources needs to retrieve data from a Map in response to a GET request.

I can't figure out how I can inject this Map into the resource, since with Jersey I don't control how the resource is initialized.

I realize I could just declare the Map as static but that seems like a very ugly solution.

Comment: Surely there is a way to achieve this very basic thing in Jersey without pulling in a massive dependency like Spring?!

Comment: Where is your map initiated usually? You can create public constructor in your resource and initialize it there, but please not it will be called for every request (unless you annotate it with  @Singleton).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the solution, I need to create a "Provider", as follows:

```
@Provider
public class DBPoolInjectableProvider extends SingletonTypeInjectableProvider<Context, BoneCPDataSource> {

    public DBPoolInjectableProvider() throws SQLException {
        super(BoneCPDataSource.class, APIMain.getDBPool());
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this case I actually needed to get access to a database connection pool, but the same idea will work for any other type of object.

I just put this provider in a package that is scanned by Jersey and it picks it up and uses it whenever it sees a method like this in a Jersey resource:

```
public TestResponse testGet(@Context final BoneCPDataSource ds) throws SQLException {
   ...
}
```

(Personally I think that this kind of "action at a distance" is an anti-pattern, but I've got it working now so I'll shut up)

Comment: Since Jersey 2 `SingletonTypeInjectableProvider` is no longer available. HK2 is now the preferred way: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/server/CustomInjectablesResourceConfigTest.java

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Create a filter which has access to a map which you need.
- Declare a thread local variable in the Filter
- Before processing request, put a map into the variable
- In your resource, when you need to have access to the map, access that local variable
- After processing request, clean this map.

It's actually, almost the same as declaring a session per request with Hibernate/JPA.